# Rare event confusion matrix

Tags: confusion-matrix, rare-events

Right now I'm gathering data collected from several individuals and manually classifying 100 randomly selected data points from each one. The 
condition I'm looking for is pretty rare. It occurs only about 5%-10% of the time. I have a metric which I am using to test for the condition.

I've looked at my data and used the metric to create a confusion matrix. In effect I am conducting a random survey of the population of available data and that should give me a good evaluation of the metric itself. I get an Accuracy of 90%-95%. I'm also aware of the Accuracy Paradox. With such a rare event I could always claim it didn't occur and be right 85%-90% of the time.

Is there a method to counteract the rarity of the event so that I can determine if the metric is effective?